# Apache mod_rewrite going berserk - redirecting where it shouldn't

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a script that echoes a meta redirect to a page called account_management.php5, but for some reason it automatically redirects from there to index.php5. My .htaccess file handles a couple of redirects automatically, for example index.html|php5 to the domain root, and that's the only place I can see this problem originating, but I don't understand why. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#remember to change this to aromaclear
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sinaesthesia\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sinaesthesia.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php5|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php5|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#translate any .html ending into .php5
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1\.php5

#change / for ?
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/(.*)$ /$1\.html?$2

#strip .html from search res page
RewriteRule ^(.*)search/(.*)$ /$1search_results\.html/search=$2

#translate product details link from search res page
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /product_details.php5?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L]

#Translate products/psorisis/chamomile-skin-cream-P[x] to productview.php5?id=1
RewriteRule ^products/.*-P([0-9]+) /productview.php5?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You have many weird conds there. Why are you comparing to THE_REQUEST? This is totally weird.

Comment: That's copied straight from a site on mod-rewrite...it didn't explain in any detail why it works, just that it does.  I cheat like a whore *shrugs*

Comment: Is there a file/directory with a name similar to “account_management”?

Comment: Fixed - I was missing a line in account_management.php that redirects if there is a session variable missing, i.e. if a user isn't signed in.  I wrote it myself, but weeks ago.  Bad memory.

Answer (score 1):

Add this just after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog /tmp/rw.log
```

Then restart the webserver.  It should help you debug the problem.

---

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't notice the `.htaccess` above.  This will only work from the main apache configuration file.

Comment: Hm, the server is remote, and I have no control over it. I can upload my own log file, but will that log errors without restarting the server?

Comment: It acually goas in the .htaccess, so I guess you have access over it. Just modify it to make the logs go somewhere you can access.

Comment: The `RewriteLogLevel` and `RewriteLog` directive are both not allowed in the .htaccess file. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: +1 for RewriteLog. It can be a huge help in sorting out what mod_rewrite is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1\.php5
```

Right:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php5
```

Righter:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php5 [QSA]
```

This same mistake of escaping special chars in the second param of RewriteRule is happening in other rules too, I don't know if apache will handle it, but I know you don't need it because second param is not a regexp.

Never compare to `%{THE_REQUEST}`, thats a weird thing to do, you don't need that. Moreover, this condition is fine without it. Just put there:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php5|html)$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Now look at it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/(.*)$ /$1.html?$2
```

First, you are still accepting that there are references to .html files, just after trying to translate all .html to .php5, there's something wrong here.
Moreover, you are defineing as QueryString something that was originally a file path, and are not even putting it in a key. It won't work, it need some more treatment.

```
#strip .html from search res page
RewriteRule ^(.*)search/(.*)$ /$1search_results.html/search=$2
```

Wasn't it supposed to strip the .html? Because it is actually **putting** a .html there. Maybe as it is not an [L] it get fixed in the next loop, but you could just get all fixed right here.

```
#translate product details link from search res page
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /product_details.php5?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

This one full of .* is potentially unstable, specially delimitating the end. You should do this:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /product_details.php5?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L]
# or:
RewriteRule ^products/(.*?)/(.*?)/([^/]*) /product_details.php5?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

The last one looks correct, except that you should strip the special character that may be faced as a range delimiter, the "-". I don't think it work after a *, but just to be sure and correct the syntax:

```
RewriteRule ^products/.*\-P([0-9]+) /productview.php5?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: -1 A lot of bad or even wrong recommendations. I don’t even know where to start.

Comment: 1. Your *Righter* example is wrong: There is no group whose match could be referenced to with `$1`. 2. The QSA flag is not needed as the substitution doesn’t has a query. 3. There are examples where testing the `THE_REQUEST` value is necessary as it holds the orignial HTTP request line while other variables may have already been changed. 4. You don’t need a key to put a value in the query. 5. Why should `.*` be unstable when delimiting the pattern? Not delimiting the pattern would have a complete different meaning.

Comment: 6. The hyphen does only describe a character range when used in a character class between two characters that are not already describing a character range.

Comment: Ha, oh now I'm confused.  I am brand new to mod_rewrite, and to regex as a whole.  The pattern involving comparing THE_REQUEST and HTTP I copied verbatim from a website on mod_rewrite and it works.  It all works as I expect, or it wouldn't be there.  All I really need to know is is there anything wrong with the redirect one, that would redirect a page other than index.(html|php5)?  I am trying to redirect to a page called account_manangement.html, and instead getting index (or domain root, thanks to my rewriting).

Comment: ^ the above sounds ignorant - I want to know why this stuff works, of course, I'm not just looking to be spoon-fed answers, but I take what I can get, too ^.^

Comment: 1. ok, fixed; 2. you don't know that to tell it won't have a query; 3. Testing the THE_REQUEST may be necessary, but thats not one of those cases; 4. yeap, but you do need to format that, and its better to put it in a key, I just gave a good advice;

Comment: 5. .* is unstable because "greedy star" can match some / if user mess around with the url. read the regular expressions expecification; 6. not sure about that, I already have cases where I got to escape the -, otherwise it was giving errors.

Comment: @Havenard: To 2.: Your *substitution URL* has no query specified. An that’s the decisive factor for whether you need the QSA flag or not. – To 4.: “It won’t work” is not just a good advice for best practice. – To 5.: That’s true, but why does it make the expression unstable? The behavior of the expression is still predictable.